# Java android GcmTaskService

Tags: java, android

I want to do a service which works all rhe time and period time. I want to do a service whic works that a phone is locked and sleep and a task never be a killed,I did this :

```
public static void scheduleRepeat(Context context) {
        try {
            Preferences prefs;
            prefs = new Preferences(context);
            long maxDiff = prefs.getInteger(Preferences.Key.CFG_USER_POSITION_FREQUENCY);

            PeriodicTask periodic = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
                    .setService(MyTaskService.class)
                    .setPeriod(maxDiff)
                    .setFlex(10)
                    .setTag(GCM_REPEAT_TAG)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                    .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_ANY)
                    .setRequiresCharging(false)
                    .build();
            GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context).schedule(periodic);
            Log.v(TAG, "repeating task scheduled");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "scheduling failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

        GcmNetworkManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .cancelTask(GCM_REPEAT_TAG, MyTaskService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeTasks() {
        super.onInitializeTasks();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {    
        return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

but somewhere I saw that a Gcm is depreceted , is this service will be work coretly all the time ?

Answer (score 0):

It has been deprecated and now you can use [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)

> This library uses the scheduling engine inside Google Play
>   services(formerly the GCM Network Manager component) to provide a
>   backwards compatible (back to Gingerbread) JobScheduler-like API.

Comment: But Job dispatcher is for api > 21 I need for api <21

Comment: WorkManager is now the solution for scheduling background jobs : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager . It supports api levels 14-23+)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure, what you are trying to do, but at the first sight it seems to me that you might use `Timer` class and `TimerTask`. However you also may try using `Handler.postDelayed()` (this will execute on the main thread).

In general, many of the Google APIs are replaced with Firebase, visit [their official site](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=ru) for more info.

Comment: I try do this but when a phone is locked this task android falls asleep and it stop working

Comment: @Kala try using Firebase then. It is quite convenient and well-documented.